# Android system landscap and portrait control

Tags: android, controls, system, landscape, portrait

I tried to develop an android application that control the android system to be in landscape or portrait mode. I have tried some code but it just control my application in landscap and portrait mode.
So here I need your help.
Could someone explain to me how to do it please ? I have write some code but I think that it is not interresant to put here.

Comment: Did you use modifiers on your layout folder? `layout` and `layout-land`?

Comment: I think you need to create a custom ROM, OS screen mode is out of your app's scope.

Comment: When I use `layout` and `layout-land`, only my app will be changed orientation. But what I'd like to do is to change entire android system orientation by using my app.  Sorry for the delay in responding, because I don't have a permenente connection

Comment: How to create a custom ROM @CodeRanger ? Could you give me a link showing how to do that please ?

Comment: Just search the web, but it may requires more than android development and java/kotlin. you are going to change the android OS. here is the google link.
https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements
but before jumping into OS details, make sure you have tested any other method.
maybe there is some permission or system manager doing that.